# Pass javascript var to ajax load

Tags: javascript, ajax, variables

Soo I do an ajax load to load a php file in my website. however I need to pass the variable "needednumber" to this php file. How would I do this? And how would I open it in the php file?

```
<script>
    var arr = <?php echo json_encode($arr) ?>;

    function deletefunction(pass) 
    {

    var needednumber = arr[pass];

    //$description = $_POST['needednumber'];
    $('#ajax').load('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/deletefavorite.php?choices=<?php echo $description; ?>');

    }
```

Comment: Aren't you already doing that by passing `<?php $description ?>`?

Comment: This was a php variable that I passed. however php is only read on the loading of the page. So it was always the same variabl.
The javascript dictates a certain variable that you choose on the website. So it has to be this variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. I did it with the following:

```
$.ajax({
                           type: "GET",
                           url: "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/deletefavorite.php",
                           data: {choices: pass},
                           success: function(result){
                             $('#ajax').html(result);
                           }
                         });

                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can try this :

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/deletefavorite.php?choices=<?php echo $description; ?>",
   success: function(result){
     $('#ajax').html(result);
   }
 });
```

or

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/deletefavorite.php",
   data: {choices: '<?php echo $description; ?>'},
   success: function(result){
     $('#ajax').html(result);
   }
 });
```

Comment: Where does this pass the javascript variable "needednumber" to the newly loaded php file??

Comment: If I do 

`$('#ajax').load('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/deletefavorite.php?choices=needednumber');`

It passed the text "needednumber" and notthe value in the variable. How would I do this?